# Error while duplicating textframe

Tags: vb.net

I m working in vb.net and the duplicate() method is throwing error.I want to duplicate textframes.
"Return argument has an invalid type"
What does this mean?

```
Dim idDupFrm As InDesign.TextFrame = idOrg_Tf.Duplicate
```

Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an article on Adobe's support site.  It says that the .Duplicate method contains some parameters that are "optional".  However, if you don't send them, it causes errors in .net.  It recommends using the command `Application.DoScript()` command to send the Duplicate command as VBScript.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/288210?start=0&tstart=0